# What is the purpose of ?? in F#?

Tags: syntax, f#

[Section 3.6](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597389) (Symbolic Keywords) of The F# 2.0 Language Specification lists the symbolic keyword ?? (double question mark) as *in use today* (i.e., not as *reserved for future use*). What is its purpose? It is not mentioned in the [Symbol and Operator Reference (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) on msdn, it does not appear to be an OCAML symbol, and I have never seen an example where it is used.

### Edit

One conceivable answer is that ?? is a symbolic keyword reserved for future use, which was accidentally placed in the list of *symbolic keywords* instead of *future symbolic keywords*. This would be strange, for two reasons:

- The list of future symbolic keywords contains only two entries: ~ and `, and it is placed immediately under the other list. Future symbolic keywords are something very prominent, it is improbable that the spec writer simply forgot about it.
- [Section 3.7](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597390) (Symbolic Operators) states that no library- or user-defined symbolic operator must start with a question mark, except for the late binding operators ? and ?<-. Therefore, it does not make sense to even mention a future symbolic keyword named ??, as its introduction cannot possibly be a breaking change.

Comment: The spec says it's treated as a keyword. Does that necessarily mean it's in use? I can tell you, it isn't.

Comment: @Daniel - I guess your comment would be perfectly good as an answer. (That is, the symbolic keyword `??` is _in use today_ as a symbolic keyword _reserved for future use_ :-))

Comment: @Daniel: This answer is OK for me, insofar as it confirms that I have not missed anything as a "user" of the language. However - just for curiosity - I would still like to know what the compiler-internal purpose is, especially since there are no other such peculiar symbols.

Comment: @Marc: I'll venture to guess it's yet to be defined. It's seems like it's no more than a way to reserve it for future use. Why the F# team decided to treat it as a keyword instead of "reserved for future use" (a la "method," "pure," etc.) I don't know.

Comment: @Tomas: I thought something like that at first, but then, to be consistent, it would really have to be listed under "future use". Other possibilities I might imagine are: a) For some esoteric reason, the compiler cannot function if such a symbol exists anywhere in the code, b) the symbol existed in an earlier version of the language, and the writers forgot to remove it from the spec, and c) it is just an error in the spec -:)

Comment: @Marc - I think the F# team just reserved some syntax in case they needed it later and wanted to avoid breaking changes. For example there are suggestions to add `foo?Bar` to C# as an operator that invokes `Bar` if `foo != null`. F# already uses `foo?Bar` for dynamic invoke, so it might use `foo??Bar` (for this or for something else). If it wasn't treated specially, you could define operator `??` and the possible change would break your code... (**EDIT** (after reading your comment) - Yes, I'm not quite sure why it isn't listed as _future use_. That might be spec error)

Answer (score 3):

The spec only says it's treated as a keyword, which apparently does not necessitate its implementation.